# test failed hive connection when configuring radoop

Tags: hadoop, hive, rapidminer

i have successfully installed and configured hadoop 2.6.2, hive 2.1.1 and spark 2.3.1.
when i run jps i have this:

```
1472 NameNode
3856 DataNode
12756 Jps
14164 SparkSubmit
14228 NodeManager
7544 GUILauncher
10860 RunJar
12524 ResourceManager
```

when i m trying to configure hadoop with rapidminer it gives the below error:

```
[Aug 11, 2018 10:28:23 AM]: Integration test for 'hadoop' started.
[Aug 11, 2018 10:28:23 AM]: Removed test Kerberos beacuse Security is not enabled
[Aug 11, 2018 10:28:23 AM]: Using Radoop version 9.0.0.
[Aug 11, 2018 10:28:23 AM]: Running 25 tests: [Hive connection, Fetch dynamic settings, Java version, NameNode networking, DataNode networking, YARN services networking, HDFS, MapReduce, Radoop temporary directory, MapReduce staging directory, Spark staging directory, Spark assembly jar existence, UDF jar upload, Create permanent UDFs, HDFS upload, Radoop jar upload, Hive load data, Import job, SQL query (aggregation), Spark job, Hive export, UDF query, Distributed Cache, UDAF query, Job kill]
[Aug 11, 2018 10:28:23 AM]: Running test 1/25: Hive connection
[Aug 11, 2018 10:28:23 AM]: Hive server 2 connection (localhost:10000) test started.
[Aug 11, 2018 10:28:24 AM] SEVERE: Test failed: Hive connection
[Aug 11, 2018 10:28:24 AM]: Cleaning after test: Hive connection
[Aug 11, 2018 10:28:24 AM]: Total time: 1.093s
[Aug 11, 2018 10:28:24 AM]: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hive/metastore/api/MetaException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:104)
    at com.rapidminer.extension.jdbc.tools.jdbc.DriverAdapter.connect(DriverAdapter.java:40)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at eu.radoop.datahandler.hive.PooledStatement.lambda$connect$0(PooledStatement.java:214)
    at eu.radoop.tools.ExceptionTools.check(ExceptionTools.java:301)
    at eu.radoop.datahandler.hive.PooledStatement.connect(PooledStatement.java:189)
    at eu.radoop.datahandler.hive.StatementPool.getStatement(StatementPool.java:314)
    at eu.radoop.datahandler.hive.StatementPool.getStatement(StatementPool.java:181)
    at eu.radoop.datahandler.hive.HiveHandler.runFastQueryPrivilegedAction(HiveHandler.java:1010)
    at eu.radoop.datahandler.hive.HiveHandler.runFastQuery(HiveHandler.java:986)
    at eu.radoop.datahandler.hive.HiveHandler.getSimpleListFast(HiveHandler.java:2575)
    at eu.radoop.datahandler.hive.HiveHandler.getTableList(HiveHandler.java:2507)
    at eu.radoop.connections.service.test.connection.TestHiveConnection.call(TestHiveConnection.java:51)
    at eu.radoop.connections.service.test.connection.TestHiveConnection.call(TestHiveConnection.java:25)
    at eu.radoop.connections.service.test.RadoopTestContext.lambda$runTest$1(RadoopTestContext.java:279)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.MetaException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 20 more

[Aug 11, 2018 10:28:24 AM] SEVERE: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hive/metastore/api/MetaException
[Aug 11, 2018 10:28:24 AM] SEVERE: Hive server 2 connection test failed. Please check that the server/daemon runs and is accessible on the address and port you specified.
[Aug 11, 2018 10:28:24 AM] SEVERE: Test failed: Hive connection
[Aug 11, 2018 10:28:24 AM] SEVERE: Integration test for 'hadoop' failed.
```

I work on apache distribution and apache port are default port (10000).

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Are you sure that version of Hive is supported by this tool?

Comment: rapidminer is supported by : Apache Hadoop 2.2+, Apache HiveServer2 0.13+, Apache Spark 1.5.x, 1.6.x, 2.0.x (except 2.0.1), 2.1.x, 2.2.x

Comment: I somewhat doubt HiveServer2 `0.13+` includes Hive 2.x or Hive 3.x, based on that error. Try using a Hive 1.x release